# Python is filtering out currency markers

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

**Objective**:
Write a screenscraper that cycles through a selection of web pages containing old prices and new prices, reads in the prices, and writes them to a CSV file.

**Method**:
The config file urls.txt contains the list of pages. Open that file and cycle through the URLs. For each URL, use Beautiful Soup to extract the contents of any divs of class "current-price" and "old-price". Not all pages will have an old price, so I've made that optional.

**Problem**:
It's all working fine but with one curious exception. Where prices are in dollars, the price and the dollar sign are coming through. Where prices are in Euros or Pounds Sterling, the currency markers £ and € are being stripped off. I want the currency markers to come through in all cases. I suspect it's an encoding issue. (The lstrip calls below are to remove some errant spaces and tabs that were coming through.)

**Contents of urls.txt:**

```
http://uk.norton.com/norton-security-for-one-device
http://uk.norton.com/norton-security-antivirus
http://uk.norton.com/norton-security-with-backup
http://us.norton.com/norton-security-for-one-device
http://us.norton.com/norton-security-antivirus
http://us.norton.com/norton-security-with-backup
http://ie.norton.com/norton-security-for-one-device
http://ie.norton.com/norton-security-antivirus
http://ie.norton.com/norton-security-with-backup
```

**Python code:**

```
###############################################
#
# PRICESCRAPE
# Screenscraper that checks prices on PD pages
#
###############################################

# Import the modules we need
import urllib.request
import re
import lxml
from lxml import etree
from lxml.html.soupparser import fromstring
from lxml.etree import tostring
from lxml.cssselect import CSSSelector
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString

# Open the files we need
out = open('out.csv', 'w')
urls=open('urls.txt','r')

# function to take a URL, open the HTML, and return it
def getPage(url):
    return urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode(encoding='UTF-8',errors='strict').encode('ascii','ignore')

out.write('URL,Current Price,Strikethrough Price\n')



#Loop through the URLs
for url in urls:
    print('\nExamining ' + url) 
    url=url.rstrip('\n')
    html=getPage(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
    currentPrice = soup.find('div', {'class': 'current-price'}).contents[0].lstrip('\n').lstrip(' ').lstrip('\t')
    oldPrice = soup.find('div', {'class': 'old-price'}).contents[0].lstrip(' ')

    out.write(url)
    out.write(',')
    out.write(str(currentPrice))
    out.write(',')
    if oldPrice:
        out.write(str(oldPrice))
    else:
         out.write('No strikethrough price')
    out.write('\n')

    if html =='':
        print('Problem reading page')

print('Done. See out.csv for output')

out.close()
urls.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use two modules to make it work and make the code simpler:

- [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) to export the results into `csv` output file
- [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) to make the encoding part transparent for you

If you would `import requests` and replace `getPage` implementation with:

```
def getPage(url):
    return requests.get(url).content
```

You would get the prices with the Euro and Pound signs as well.